# Can't see sidebar items displayed in my custom template

Tags: wordpress

I am a new user of Wordpress. I have developed in php for several years and I am trying to understand the logics of WP. I have created a basic site configuring a top primary menu, a primary sidebar with widgets, and a footer.

I have created a custom template in which I would like to insert some code I have developed. I'd like as well the custom template to use and display the default theme header, sidebar and footer (for your information I am using the twentyfourteen theme).

Based on my understanding I have started naming the template and inserting the header, sidebar and footer  to see if everything would display correctly before adding my own code :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Test template
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I was expecting to see a page with "no content", just with the top menu, the sidebar and the footer menus and elements. Unfortunately it looks like the sidebar elements are not displayed. The top menu works but not all the widgets in the footer work correctly.

On the other hand if I have a look on the source code of the page, the elements of the sidebar are indeed there but I believe that for a certain reason (due to the stylesheets??) they are not displayed.

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: Can you provide your code for side bar ?

Comment: Do you mean the source code of the entire page that is displayed?

Comment: Not entire...The code where you have defined your sidebar part ..

Comment: In fact I didn't define any code for the sidebar. The only thing I did was to create a template page containing the code specified above.

Comment: to call the sidebar I just specified 
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

Comment: you got wrong definition.Go through this [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).Yo need to register sidebar to have the widgets from backend.You need to define it `register_sidebar` in `functions.php` file

Answer (score 1):

To Check

Do you have a file called sidebar.php

Secondly, you have set this up as  a template have you assigned the template to the page?

It may sound daft but this can occur an awful lot.

Comment: Yes I have assigned the file to a page. The page displays very nicely with the header part, the footer part and the standard layout of the sidebar.

The only problem is that there is no content in the sidebar. The weird thing is that when I look into the page code in the browser, the code of the sidebar elements is indeed there, but it does not display.

Since lots of things seem to be handled by the stylesheets my doubt is that I am missing something in my "custom template" code.

Comment: post the code from your sidebar template file and il deffinatly try and help you.

Comment: do you mean the one of sidebar.php?

Comment: yes so open sidebar.php and copy everything in that file and paste it here. or post a link.

Comment: make sure both of them sidebars are created in to your functions and have something assigned to them. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: seond point drop the display filter from get_bloginfo() its not actually required.